# How to display param value in DB and not?

Tags: javascript, typescript, database

I have a typescript and DB question. I generate a uuid as a ticket like so and I can see when I console log it, it displays the uuid as expected.

I then want to take that param value and insert it into the database. However, I notice in the DB instead of showing the uuid value, it is displaying a '?'. How do I add a param value into the DB?

```
const ticketId: string = uuidv4(); //632d8ea6-ff67-4069-b97c-8c23aa0104dd

await addItem(ticketId);
```

...

```
export function addItem(ticketId: string) {

  const query = sql`INSERT INTO test.ticket (ticket.uuid)
  VALUES ("${ticketId}")`;
  console.log(query);
  return execute(query);
}
```

console log shows this:

```
{
      text: 'INSERT INTO test.ticket (ticket.uuid)\n' +
        '  VALUES ("$1",)',
      sql: 'INSERT INTO test.ticket (ticket.uuid)\n' +
        '  VALUES ("?")',
      values: [ '632d8ea6-ff67-4069-b97c-8c23aa0104dd' ]
}
```

Screenoshot of mysql workbench showing the db row:
[image]

Comment: Does the code not work tho? the question mark should be replaced by values when executing

Comment: It looks like it's being parameterized, replacing the "?" with the actual value upon insertion. Have you checked the DB itself to see what was inserted?

Comment: Yeah it's weird, the code passes fine but when I look at the DB it shows ? in the table row

Comment: @mykaf Yeah that's what I meant in my question that when I look into the DB itself, it displays ?

Comment: Does your db required single quotes? What DB are you using? Can you post a screenshot of your DB record?

Comment: Using mysql workbench and let me try the single quotes...

Comment: Single quotes did not work. Damn. I added the screenshot in the question

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, ensure there is no quotation around the param. So it should be:

```
const query = sql`INSERT INTO test.ticket (ticket.uuid)
  VALUES (${ticketId})`;
```

NOT

```
const query = sql`INSERT INTO test.ticket (ticket.uuid)
  VALUES ("${ticketId}")`;
```

Answer (score -1):

It's a parameterized query to the DB.
It has some pros.

1. Guard from [sql injections](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp) as the real value arrive from a specific parameter it's harder to tweek it to run other code.
2. [Performance](https://medium.com/@abelzerihun/understanding-parameterized-queries-3c4d81acbf41): when the query is created and compiled in the sql instance, the next time you will use the same query it will be already optimized and the engine doesn't have to compile it again.

What you need to check is what will return from a fetch query.
Like this one:

```
select * from test.ticket
```

Comment: It's deffo inseted a ?. I tried select * from test.ticket where ticket.uuid = 632d8ea6-ff67-4069-b97c-8c23aa0104dd and doesn't find it. Replaced the uuid with ? and it found the record